# Importing data using MySQL Administrator

Tags: mysql, excel

I currently have a *massive* excel file of which the data i'd like to import it into my **already setup MySQL Server and Table**

I have MySQL Administrator installed, so I was wondering if MySQL Admin can import excel files to SQL tables or if I should install another program to do what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Database/Converting-Your-Excel-Worksheet-into-a-Working-MySQL-Database/ and it worked perfectly fine